# How to Fix the error relevant to keyboard layout in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I can't run codes that contain semi column key or shift and ' hotkey on AutoHotkey. I face these errors:

**Note: The hotkey +' will not be active because it does not exist in the current keyboard layout.**

**Note: The hotkey ; will not be active because it does not exist in the current keyboard layout.**

I don't know why I always face these errors I searched on internet but still don't know how to fix the error.

Comment: [This](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/123106-the-key-will-not-be-active-because-it-does-not-exist-in-the-current-keyboard/) AHK forum post suggests using the vk code instead of the key name.

Comment: Are you using a different language/ special keyboard layout?

Comment: @Spyre Yes. I am using other language beside English. and also I changed my keyboard recently. I didn't face this error with my old keyboard.

Comment: If you run into trouble figuring out which vk code to use, [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) is the relevant documentation.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong it is confusing for me. for example I want to press shift and semi column the virtual key for semi column is  VK_OEM_10xBA but I don't know how to write it ``+{VKOEM10xBA}::`` didn't work.