# Having problem with using Virtual keyboard code in Autohot Key

Tags: autohotkey

From the error I explained in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963767/how-to-fix-the-error-relevant-to-keyboard-layout-in-autohotkey?noredirect=1#comment116629197_65963767) It turns out I should use Virtual Keyboard code for the keys that I face error.

I want to use virtual code for hotkey +' (Which is pressing Shift and ' at the same time) and for the key ; (semi-column) (more specifically I want to use hotkey +' to click on a coordinate and the key ; to click on other coordinate) but I have problem writing the code. I found list of Virtual Keys [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/98757-how-to-create-a-new-virtual-keys/) but unfortunately I don't know how to use them to write code.

**Edit:**

For pressing semi-column (;)  I tried this key:

```
[vkBA27]::
Click,885,234
return
```

But It says it is invalid hotkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [AutoHotkey documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys):

> If your keyboard or mouse has a key not listed above, you might still be able to make it a hotkey by using the following steps:
>
> 1. Ensure that at least one script is running that is using the keyboard hook. You can tell if a script has the keyboard hook by opening its main window and selecting "View->Key history" from the menu bar.
> 2. Double-click that script's tray icon to open its main window.
> 3. Press one of the "mystery keys" on your keyboard.
> 4. Select the menu item "View->Key history"
> 5. Scroll down to the bottom of the page. Somewhere near the bottom are the key-down and key-up events for your key. NOTE: Some keys do not generate events and thus will not be visible here. If this is the case, you cannot directly make that particular key a hotkey because your keyboard driver or hardware handles it at a level too low for AutoHotkey to access. For possible solutions, see further below.
> 6. If your key is detectable, make a note of the 3-digit hexadecimal value in the second column of the list (e.g. 159).
> 7. To define this key as a hotkey, follow this example:
>
> ```
> SC159:: ; Replace 159 with your key's value.
> MsgBox, %A_ThisHotkey% was pressed.
> return
> ```

Interpreting the example above, we know that the format for a hotkey declaration using a virtual key is:

```
SC<Hex code>::
<Your code here>
Return
```

I can only assume "SC" stands for "Scan Code".  Using the steps above, I can see that the scan code (the documentation refers to it as the "3-digit hexadecimal value") for <kbd>;</kbd> is `027`, and the scan code for <kbd>'</kbd> is `028`.  This allows me to construct your hotkey definitions like so:

```
SC027::
<Your code for ; here>

+SC028::
<Your code for SHIFT+' here>
```

Comment: Some corrections: There is no such thing as "scan code (SC) for x key". You could say "SC for x key on x keyboard". E.g for me the key on my keyboard marked as `'` produces SC `2B`, which Windows then maps to virtual key (VK) `BF` on my keyboard layout. Keys on your keyboard are associated with SCs, and Windows will then map the SC it receives to a VK based off the current keyboard layout in effect (among other things). You can view it all in more detail from the [Windows SDK header `kbd.h`](https://pastebin.com/hS5kyUyK). To specify an AHK hotkey with a VK, you'd do e.g `vkBF::`